# Find disjoint groups (Connected Components) in a set of vectors

Tags: r

N vectors of different lengths (>=2) are given. For example, a,b,c,d,e,f,g and h are given by:

```
 a <- (e1,e2,e3)
 b <- (e4,e5,e7,e8)
 c <- (e9,e10)
 d <- (e2,e10)
 e <- (e15,e1)
 f <- (e4,e12)
 g <- (e9,e19)
 h <- (e20,e21)
```

My question is that how can we generate group of the vectors from the connected vectors out of a,b...g and h (by using R language). In this case output will be
(a,d,c,e,g), (b,f) and (h).
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: This is a hypergraph, right? And you want to look for the connected components?

Comment: Right Martin. I have to find connected components out of these vectors.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't think this is an exact duplicate -- the question you linked is would return output like (e1, e2, e9, e15, e3, e10, e19), (e4, e5, e7, e8, e12), (e20, e21), while the OP wants output (a, d, c, e, g), (b, f), (h).

Comment: I would think the hard part is finding the disjoint groups. The strategy would be exactly the same, you just change what you return. I do not see it as meaningfully different.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't see how you would do this without an additional step of looking up groupings (a, b, c) matching the components from the graph (using `sapply` or similar), meaning there's an additional step required for this question. This doesn't seem identical, so I've voted to reopen.

Comment: If the OP had indicated any attempt to create the disjoint set, I might believe you. There was no indication that the grouping of the results was the particular problem that was faced. All you need to do is add a node property for group name. Then you can select the distinct group names in each of the clusters.

Comment: @MrFlick & Josiber: In the final output, I have to show each connected component in the graph form. For example, for  (a,d,c,e,g) can I show a graph with vertices a,d,c,e,g and edges:e1 for (a,e), e2 for (a,d), e10 for (c,d), e9 for (c,g). If graphical representation is not possible in R, then please suggest me some library for text form representation.

Comment: The igraph library which we used to find the disjoint groups can certainly also be used to plot the results. It may not necessarily find a minimal set of connecting edges. Not sure how much you want to automate or have precise control over.